# ipad safari shows a backgroundimage (fixed, cover) much bigger and so very pixely

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari

I'm having an issue with the safari browser on ipad. 
As I'm not having one by myself it's a bit difficult to try around, but I'm working on it.

The problem: 
I'm having a background image fixed + background-size: cover
On all the browser on the desktop it looks fine. But the safari mobile on ipad shows the pic kind of huge and so really pixely.
The container has: (the most important)

```
width:100%;
background:url("...") no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size:cover;
```

I don't know how to fix it, do you have any idea?

Here you see a pic of the ipad: 
[image: ipad]

Comment: Your problem description `I'm having a background image fixed + background-size: cover` doesn't make sense.

Comment: This could be due to a higher display DPI on the iPad, causing the image to be scaled up in order to display at the same relative size.